# String replacement (to lowercase) in Bash 4.3.33 - bad substitution error

Tags: string, bash, replace, substitution, lowercase

I'm trying to change uppercase to lowercase using string replacement in bash, but i'm getting a bad substitution error.

```
> a=HEY
> echo $a 
HEY 
> echo ${a,,}
-bash: ${a,,}: bad substitution
# desired output is hey
```

I've seen similar questions to this, but in most cases it was down to using an earlier version of bash. I'm using GNU bash 4 and still having the same problems.

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0)
```

This is a Mac thing maybe? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not providing a pattern at the end is a shortcut for doing `${a,,?}`.  What happens if you try `${a,,?}` explicitly?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.33` - `$ ( a=HEY; echo ${a,,} )` yields `hey` without a problem?

Comment: Are you sure your current shell is bash 4? Maybe your session runs in OS X default bash 3? Try `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: @baf That's got to be it. I just tested with `3.2.39` and got `-bash: ${a,,}: bad substitution`. It looks like OP may have bash 4 installed, but has a bash 3 (or other) shell running.

Comment: @baf yes! you're right. 
echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release
Cheers!

Comment: This might be obvious, If you have installed using homebrew it will install bash 4 in /usr/local/bin/bash AFAIK so usually opening a new command window will run bash 4 but if you put '#!/bin/bash' in a script it will find the system bash 3.  Best to use '#!/usr/bin/env bash' to get the correct version.

To get the version from the current shell use echo `$BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: @lokulin not so obvious to me :) thanks for the info

Comment: work-a-round:
`echo $a | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` ?

Comment: @kecso good suggestion, however I'd say it's not a workaround since `tr` is there to do exactly that kind of transform (among others).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the bash that is first in `PATH` happens to be 4.3.33, but the bash you're running in the interactive session is probably an older version. Run `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to check.

If the above is correct, run

```
type bash
```

to see the path of the newer version, probably something like `/opt/local/bin/bash`. I'll assume it is. If you want that to be your login shell, first add it to /etc/shells

```
sudo -e /etc/shells
```

After that, users are allowed to select that as their login shell by using the `chsh` (**ch**ange **sh**ell) command

```
chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash
```

Comment: I'm on a company computer. Therefore, I can't upgrade bash. Does anyone know an alternative for lowercase conversion?

Comment: `awk '{print tolower($0)}' <<< "$var"` or `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:'] <<< "$var"` though if you have GNU tr, it only handles conversion of ascii letters, while BSD tr handles utf-8, so if you're on MacOS, use the tr. If you're on GNU/linux, use the awk.

Comment: sweet thanks. awk is a useful tool I feel most people don’t know about.

Comment: Same problem in WSL, debian running under windows.  bash 4.4.20, but 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"' is empty and the string replacements don't work

Comment: @andrewlorien use `adduser` instead of `useradd` to create a user; the defaults of `adduser` gives the user a homedir and bash as login shell, while the defaults of `useradd` gives the user sh as login shell and no homedir.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments on my comment, this is the answer:

```
echo $a | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: Thanks kecso, tr is always a good workaround. My question was really about why string replacement wasn't working though, rather than trying to get the same result by a different means.